# C#, Async Tasks and NetworkStream.BeginRead, how to guarantee the buffer won't be overwritten?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to write a piece of code in C# to read from a TcpClient asynchronously. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Connection
{
    private TcpClient socket;
    private NetworkStream socketStream;
    private byte[] buffer;
    private int bytesRead;
    private Task<int> readTask;

    public Connection(TcpClient socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        socketStream = socket.GetStream();
        buffer = new byte[4096];

        readTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<byte[], int, int, int>(
            this.socketStream.BeginRead
            , this.socketStream.EndRead
            , this.buffer
            , 0
            , this.buffer.Length
            , null
        );
        readTask.ContinueWith(
            (task) => {
                this.bytesRead = (int)task.Result;
                //Do something with buffer.
            }
            , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that the asynchronous BeginRead will try to write over the Connection object's buffer and once a new data arrives the old one will be overwritten regardless of whether it is consumed or not. How should I tackle this problem? AFAIK it should have something to do with closures but I can't figure it out how!

Comment: You'd have to have a collection of buffers that you need to process.  You could simply allocate a local buffer (`var buffer = new byte[4096];`) then add that buffer to a collection (maybe `Stack`) in the continuation.  You'll probably also end up having to deal with notifying another thread to process new data in the queue.  but, you really haven't presented enough information to really tell what you really need for this situation.  e.g. *why* hasn't the previous buffer been processed yet?

Comment: I have already got another version of this code properly working with `Threads`. But here I was trying to rewrite the code to use `Task` and `Asynchronous` delegates. BTW, for your solution to work I need to be able to copy the buffer into the `Stack` within the first `Task`. I mean there's no guarantee that before the second `Task` is started there won't be another instance of first one executed. As a matter of fact now that I think of it, the only way for this code to work at all times would be the first task to return a newly created buffer so the 2nd one can use it. But I have no idea how!

Comment: If it's a locally allocated buffer, each task will have it's own buffer.

Comment: Then I must ask how are you going to access a locally allocated buffer in the second task when it is allocated in the first one? I mean that would definitely solve my problem.

Comment: The compiler will capture the outer variable and extend its lifetime into the continuation as well as make it accessible "after the fact".

Comment: Would you please write it down in code? I'm not sure if I get you correctly! Anyway I see it, if the buffer is not allocated in the first task and passed on to the second one, there's always the chance to be overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to have a collection of buffers that you need to process. You could simply allocate a local buffer (`var buffer = new byte[4096];`) then add that buffer to a collection (maybe `Stack`) in the continuation. You'll probably also end up having to deal with notifying another thread to process new data in the queue.

For example:

```
class Connection
{
    private TcpClient socket;
    private NetworkStream socketStream;
    private int bytesRead;
    private Task<int> readTask;
    private Stack<byte[]> buffersToProcess;
    private readonly object lockObject = new object();

    public Connection(TcpClient socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        socketStream = socket.GetStream();
        var buffer = new byte[4096];

        readTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<byte[], int, int, int>(
            this.socketStream.BeginRead
            , this.socketStream.EndRead
            , buffer
            , 0
            , buffer.Length
            , null
            );
        readTask.ContinueWith(
            (task) =>
                {
                    this.bytesRead = (int) task.Result;
                    var actualBytes = new byte[bytesRead];
                    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, actualBytes, 0, bytesRead);
                    lock (lockObject)
                    {
                        buffersToProcess.Push(actualBytes);
                    }
                    // TODO: do something with buffersToProcess
                }
            , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
            );
    }
}
```

But, you really haven't presented enough information to really tell what you really need for this situation. e.g. why hasn't the previous buffer been processed yet?

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but how is it guaranteed that the first task won't overwrite the buffer before the second one copies it?

Comment: "Second task", do you mean the `ContinueWith`?  `ContinueWith` is called when the first task is *done*, it's not doing anything else, let alone touching the buffer you gave it.

Comment: To my knowledge `ContinueWith` is called after the first task is complete **asynchronously** which means there's always the chance for the first task to overwrite the buffer before the `ContinueWith` is carried out. Am I wrong?

Comment: The first task is *done*, it's not doing anything else.  The continuation may be asynchronous to the original thread that called `FromAsync`, but it's not asynchronous to that task because that task is *done*.  In your continuation you can start another read if you haven't read all the data (and thus introduce two asynchronous operations that may be vying for the same memory); but that's a new task.

Comment: First of all thanks for your patience. Second of all, here's the scenario I've got in my mind: consider two segments are sent from client to server. They arrive at the server so closely (in time) that the second task can not find the chance to copy the buffer. Isn't that possible? I mean the first task is executed every time there's something to read. How does the code guarantee the buffer is copied before a new request has arrived? Your answer will be correct only if no new instance of first task is started before all the continuations of previous instances are done. Which I hardly doubt that

Comment: How is that possible?  You haven't started to read another segment yet.

Comment: Isn't the first task supposed to spawn a new thread each time there's something ready to read?

Comment: No, it doesn't do that automatically.  You get "chunks" of data with `BeginRead` (if you don't get it all) and you process each chunk separately, then start another `BeginRead` to get the next chunk...  You're not doing that next `BeginRead`, so there's nothing else that will touch that buffer.

Comment: Sorry that I doubt your word but do you have a reference for that? I mean logically speaking, if each task runs in a different thread, there's always the chance to lose the buffer contents. Unless this is prevented internally in the .Net.

Comment: No, each task does not necessarily run in a different thread.  Task only means "asynchronous", you can have asynchronous without different threads (e.g. UI message pump--each message is asynchronous from all others but only one thread is involved).  ContinueWith means it won't be executed until the first task completed (i.e. EndRead is called--which is well documented and doesn't document other threads being created to get more data)

Comment: Here's a quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx): `After calling BeginOperationName, an application can continue executing instructions on the calling thread while the asynchronous operation takes place on a different thread.`

Comment: I've just found the problem with my way of thinking. I was assuming that by instantiating a new task, using the BeginRead, any number of incoming segments will spawn new threads. But the fact is that each task will only be responsible for one incoming segment. Once the task is used, I need to create a new one to capture the next segment. Thanks for your time.

Comment: yes.  RE the quote, that is trying to detail that you can call BeginRead, then do something else (like `Console.WriteLine("BeginRead was called")`) and the read will occur asynchronously...